# Finding an upperbound on the CDF of sum of squared Gaussian random variables around zero

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x_1, \dots, x_N$ be i.i.d. standard normal random variables. Define $y_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_n$ for $n = 1, \dots, N$, which has a Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance $n$. Note that $y_1, ..., y_N$ are not independent. Consider the following random variable $Z = \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2$. Is it possible to find an upperbound on the CDF of $Z$ around zero which tends to zero as $N \rightarrow \infty$? Specifically, for $\epsilon_N>0$ that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_N = 0$ find $U_N$ such that

$$p(Z \leq \epsilon_N) \leq U_N,$$

where $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} U_N = 0$.

My intuition is as $N$ increases, the variance of $Z$ increases, thus the probability that $Z$ is close to zero should decrease. Also, if we were looking at $V = \sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2$ instead, $V$ would have a Chi-squared distribution and we could have come up with a bound.

Comment: The variance of $Z$ increasing with $N$ does not suggest that the probability that $Z$ is close to zero should decrease (even though it does).  Empirically it seems that the standard deviation of $Z$ exceeds the mean.  I suspect it is the increase of $\mathbb EZ = \frac12N(N+1)$ which stretches the distribution and so  the probability that $Z$ is close to zero decreases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very rough estimate: $Z = \sum_{n=1}^N y_n^2 \geq y_N^2$, therefore 
$$
\mathbb P(Z \leq \epsilon_N) \leq \mathbb P(y_N^2 \leq \epsilon_N) = \mathbb P(Nx_1^2 \leq \epsilon_N)
$$
The last equality follows from $y_N\sim \mathcal N(0,N)$. Indeed, $$y_N/\sqrt{N}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$ and $y_N^2$ distributed as $Nx_1^2$.
So
$$
\mathbb P(Z \leq \epsilon_N) \leq \mathbb P\left(x_1^2 \leq \frac{\epsilon_N}{N}\right)=1-2\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon_N}{N}}\right)=U_N
$$
which tends to zero as soon as $\frac{\epsilon_N}{N}$ tends to zero.

Comment: It may be worth noting that while $y_N^2$ with mean $N$ is very slightly right skewed, $Z_N$ with with the much larger mean $\frac12N(N+1)$ seems to be heavily right skewed